# Print shipping and total costs to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce

I'm using [simplecart.js](http://simplecartjs.org) to build a small store on a website I created before. I have one problem. The whole shopping cart is displayed with only one line of code:

`<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>`

And the javascript prints the table, you can't see it in the source code. BUT, inspect element in chrome is a good friend of mine, and the table created will look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th class="item-name">Tuote</th>
            <th class="item-price">Hinta</th>
            <th class="item-decrement"></th>
            <th class="item-quantity">Määrä</th>
            <th class="item-increment"></th>
            <th class="item-total">Yhteensä</th>
            <th class="item-remove"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-3">
            <td class="item-name">Teipit (Valkoinen hiilikuitu)</td>
            <td class="item-price">€48.00</td>
            <td class="item-decrement">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a>
            </td>
            <td class="item-quantity">1</td>
            <td class="item-increment">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a>
            </td>
            <td class="item-total">€48.00</td>
            <td class="item-remove">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Poista</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I want it to print something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th class="item-name">Tuote</th>
            <th class="item-price">Hinta</th>
            <th class="item-decrement"></th>
            <th class="item-quantity">Määrä</th>
            <th class="item-increment"></th>
            <th class="item-total">Yhteensä</th>
            <th class="item-remove"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-3">
            <td class="item-name">Teipit (Valkoinen hiilikuitu)</td>
            <td class="item-price">€48.00</td>
            <td class="item-decrement">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a>
            </td>
            <td class="item-quantity">1</td>
            <td class="item-increment">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a>
            </td>
            <td class="item-total">€48.00</td>
            <td class="item-remove">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Poista</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="shippingtotal" id="shipping">
            <td class="item-name">Shipping</td>
            <td class="shipping-cost">€5.00</td>
            <td class="item-decrement">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a>
            </td>
            <td class="item-quantity">1</td>
            <td class="item-increment">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a>
            </td>
            <td class="item-total">€48.00</td>
            <td class="item-remove">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Poista</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, here's the simplecart.js itself:
http://pastebin.com/j5VKGkV1

I think that I should add something to this part of the code:

```
// write out cart
                writeCart: function (selector) {
                    var TABLE = settings.cartStyle.toLowerCase(),
                        isTable = TABLE === 'table',
                        TR = isTable ? "tr" : "div",
                        TH = isTable ? 'th' : 'div',
                        TD = isTable ? 'td' : 'div',
                        cart_container = simpleCart.$create(TABLE),
                        header_container = simpleCart.$create(TR).addClass('headerRow'),
                        container = simpleCart.$(selector),
                        column,
                        klass,
                        label,
                        x,
                        xlen;

                    container.html(' ').append(cart_container);

                    cart_container.append(header_container);


                    // create header
                    for (x = 0, xlen = settings.cartColumns.length; x < xlen; x += 1) {
                        column = cartColumn(settings.cartColumns[x]);
                        klass = "item-" + (column.attr || column.view || column.label || column.text || "cell") + " " + column.className;
                        label = column.label || "";

                        // append the header cell
                        header_container.append(
                        simpleCart.$create(TH).addClass(klass).html(label));
                    }

                    // cycle through the items
                    simpleCart.each(function (item, y) {
                        simpleCart.createCartRow(item, y, TR, TD, cart_container);
                    });

                    return cart_container;
                },

                // generate a cart row from an item
                createCartRow: function (item, y, TR, TD, container) {
                    var row = simpleCart.$create(TR).addClass('itemRow row-' + y + " " + (y % 2 ? "even" : "odd")).attr('id', "cartItem_" + item.id()),
                        j,
                        jlen,
                        column,
                        klass,
                        content,
                        cell;

                    container.append(row);

                    // cycle through the columns to create each cell for the item
                    for (j = 0, jlen = settings.cartColumns.length; j < jlen; j += 1) {
                        column = cartColumn(settings.cartColumns[j]);
                        klass = "item-" + (column.attr || (isString(column.view) ? column.view : column.label || column.text || "cell")) + " " + column.className;
                        content = cartCellView(item, column);
                        cell = simpleCart.$create(TD).addClass(klass).html(content);

                        row.append(cell);
                    }
                    return row;
                }

            });
```

But what? the shipping can be displayed with this:
`<span class="simpleCart_shipping"></span>` I've tried adding that after the cart, but it looks kind of silly.

Update: This is an example without the mofication (before):
[image: Before]
And this is what it should be like..

[image: What I need]

Comment: Do you have some working example? Copying the code gives me some errors -_-' Line 1502 e.g. says that create() doesnt exist..

Comment: And, to what extend would you mind me modifying that original code? I guess it's best to not modify the other code, I didn't check yet how often the functions are invoked (and I don't know if it will change in the future). For that reason it might be wise to not alter the createCartRow methods, but add a fully custom method without dependencies with existing code, right..

Comment: http://u31830.shellit.eu/kauppa/kassa.php

Comment: Thank you. I have updated your post. Can you clarify your request? What do you want the result to be like?

Comment: @EricG I want it to look print an additional row, and the row should contain the shipping costs.

Comment: And, if possible the **TOTAL** price of the shipping and product, like in my post.

Comment: I have implemented the other operations. You will have to do some manual testing considering the settings and the implementations overall. Can you look if it is helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off by adding this:

```
    // [..]
    header_container = simpleCart.$create(TR).addClass('headerRow'),

    // Added line
    total_container = simpleCart.$create(TR).addClass('shippingtotal').attr('id', "shipping" ),

    container = simpleCart.$(selector),
    // [..]
```

And

```
    // create header
    // [..]

    // cycle through the items
    // [..]

    // create total
    cart_container.append(total_container);
    total_container.append( createTotalShippingRow() );   // Even though invoked just once

    return cart_container;
```

And

```
createCartRow: function (item, y, TR, TD, container) {
    // [..]
},

createCartTotalShippingRow: function() {

    // Impl. look other update
}

createTotalShippingRow: function() {

    // Impl. look other update
}
```

I'll work on the impl. now :-)

Add the following to your settings.. (from http://pastebin.com/j5VKGkV1)

```
settings = {

    cartTotalColumns: [{
        attr: "name",
        label: "Name"
    }, {
        attr: "price",
        label: "Price",
        view: 'currency'
    }, {
        view: "empty",      // replaces decrement
        label: false
    }, {
        attr: "empty",      // replaces quantity
        label: false        // Qty
    }, {
        view: "empty",      // replaces increment
        label: false
    }, {
        attr: "total",
        label: "SubTotal",
        view: 'currency'
    }, {
        view: "empty",      // replaces remove
//      text: "Remove",
        label: false
    }],
}
```

Update [..]
[..removed code from update..]
Try to write reusable code (you want similair output for items & total).
Try to let the methods do what they describe they do (appending outside container, you returned the row anyways).
Try to use proper variable names.
Try to seperate different kinds of functionality.
Even in the writeCart method, you could split 'createHeader(..) createItems(..) createTotal(..)'.

Further, try to use semantic names. At least the 'y' variable should be renamed as 'rowIndex' or something.

Update:

```
createTotalShippingRow: function( TR, TD ) {

    // I think we shouldn't instantiate the item here, but you could test if this works?
    var item = {
        name: "Shipping",
        price: 5,               
//      view: "empty",      // decrement
//      attr: "empty",      // quantity
//      view: "empty",      // increment
        total: this.total(),
//      view: "empty",      // remove
        };

    var rowid = "shipping";

    return createCartTotalShippingRow( item, rowid, TR, TD );
},

createCartTotalShippingRow: function( item, rowclass, rowid, TR, TD ) {
    var row = simpleCart.$create(TR).addClass( rowclass ).attr( 'id', rowid ),
        i = 0,
        cartTotalColumns = settings.cartTotalColumns,
        ln = cartTotalColumns.length,
        column,
        classname;

    for ( ; i < ln; i++ ) {
        column = cartColumn( cartTotalColumns[ i ] );
        classname = "item-" + ( column.attr || ( isString( column.view ) ? column.view : column.label || column.text || "cell" ) ) + " " + column.className;
        content = cartCellView( item, column );
        cell = simpleCart.$create(TD).addClass(classname).html(content);
        row.append(cell);
    }

    return row;
}
```

UPDATE:

[whole file..](http://pastebin.com/FJuM0KEY) But I have the same error as I had with your original code (the method create doesn't exist). But that has nothing to do with your request by itself.

Comment: This isn't my code... So I have no idea of what I should write.

Comment: Alright I just assumed you were somewhat more familiar with the structure & invocation of code. If you're lucky (if I find the will :P ) I will take a look at it later today :')

Comment: I've been working on the implementations for a while now, but it's giving me a syntax error on Dreamweaver. Here's the full code with your implementions:http://pastebin.com/e0FxBzZz
Hopefully I've done everything correcly.

Comment: You don't have all the good sources. I will update my post with the 'whole' source :)

Comment: No offense, it disappoints me to see that you hardly seem to know what you are doing. I will paste the full code in a bit..

Comment: Here you go, I have the same error which I had from your original code. http://pastebin.com/FJuM0KEY Please let me know if you find troubles.

Comment: Hmmm. It wont add anything to the cart, but the original code worked fine, so something must have gone wrong...

Comment: The '// Impl. here' was a placeholder. COntact me by email or so.

Comment: Yeah I got that. Javascript just isn't my field, PHP is more familiar, but I just needed to use a lightweight shopping cart.